# return member object on hibernate and not Object[] row = (Object[]) ite.next();

Tags: hibernate

I´m new in Hibernate and I'm trying return HQL query like this:

```
    select u.user, up.name from Usuario  u
    join u.usuarioPersonals as up
    where u.idusuario=1
```

After I recovery this resulset in my Dao and show on console

```
    List d =  usuarioDao.test(1);

    Iterator ite = d.iterator();

    while ( ite.hasNext() ) {
          Object[] row = (Object[]) ite.next();
          System.out.print("\t\t"+row[0]);
          System.out.print("\t"+row[1]);
          System.out.println();
    }
```

My question is there no other option to get data object like Usuario.getUser() UsuarioPersonals.getName() ?

Other option is only write my hql sentence like this:

```
    from Usuario  u
    join u.usuarioPersonals as up
    where u.idusuario=1
```

And iterate on my data

```
    while ( ite.hasNext() ) {
       Object[] row = (Object[]) ite.next();
   Usuario usr = (Usuario) row[0];
       UsuarioPersonals usr = (UsuarioPersonals) row[1];
       System.out.print(usr.getUser());
       System.out.print(usr.getName());
    }
```

The last option perhaps is complex if I want send to my view through my servlet.

Sorry, I´m new in this technology and I´m looking to other option but maybe only exist this two option to send data.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the relationship between Usuario and UsuarioPersonals ? Making relationship between two entities you can traverse through objects and find values you want

Comment: Thanks, my relationship is working good, because whether show me the results if I print the Dao object. Maybe the best option if and use servlets and jsp is a map on POJO the interface, filling the POJO interface object wiht DAO result Object and send to view, I don´t know if is a good practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally don't need to specify the join.

```
 from Usuario  u
 where u.idusuario=1
```

This will return just a list of the Usuario object and you can traverse the object graph to get anything on it.

If you look at the SQL that's being produced, you'll see that the UsuarioPersonals are not there.  What's happening is Hibernate is going to produce SQL when you try to access them.  In a small application, you won't have any problem with this, but if you are trying to optimize, and you know you will always be accessing those objects, you can construct the query similar to how you are doing it now:

```
from Usuario  u
    join fetch u.usuarioPersonals as up
    where u.idusuario=1
```

This will place UsuarioPersonals data on the object so it does not require an additional database call.  Again, probably not necessary, and you can usually just select the root objects.

Comment: Thanks David! if I want optimize my app I can use root objects, can you recommend to not send row object to my view do a class where I can map my interface (like struts) and filling this object with my root object? with this option I will can access through my object property , for example usr.getName(),usr.getUser() .

Comment: Yes, if you select just a persistent entity, you can use those in your views.  If you close the session before you render the view, you won't be able to load anything lazily, so you would need to eagerly load by doing a join fetch.  A good thing to try is to turn on show_sql in your hibernate config so you can see all the SQL that is generated and know if the optimizations are working.